# Setting a database offline with powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I'm working on an automated database restore script in powershell and trying to harden it. At a high level, it goes something like this:

```
$s = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server '.';
$db = $s.Databases['myDb'];

$db.SetOffline();
# start restore here
```

The problem here is that if there are any connections in the database, the `SetOffline()` command gets blocked. I know that there are `KillDatabase()` and `KillAllProcesses()` methods on the Server object, but the former sets me up to have to zero out the log file again and the latter has a race condition on a busy server. What I'm looking for is the SMO equivalent of `alter database [myDb] set offline with rollback immediate;`.

Does such a thing exist? I could resort to doing some `ExecuteNonQuery()` shenanigans, but it seems like there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: You say "shenanigans", I say "the proper way to work around SMO". Remember that SMO is not magic -- it's an O-O interface to something that constructs and executes plain old SQL queries in the background. `.SetOffline()` produces the script `USE [master]\r\nALTER DATABASE [name] SET  OFFLINE`, with no facility for appending `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`. There isn't even any elegant way to extend SMO to do this, as it keeps its internals closely guarded (even something as simple as the code for escaping object names).

Comment: Bizarrely enough, you *can* set the database to single user `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` with SMO (`$db.UserAccess = "Single"; $db.Alter([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.TerminationClause] "RollbackTransactionsImmediately")`). But this does not solve your problem, because a race condition remains between switching the database to single user and taking it offline (or restoring over it). `SetOffline` is just missing an overload.

Comment: As far as I know, the best way to do this is by executing T-SQL :(. At my job, we ran into the race condition you mention all the time, and eventually wound up calling T-SQL to handle setting it offline. SMOs are like, fine, kinda, but have plenty of holes in our experience.

Answer (score 0):

So what if you block the access to SQL in the firewall first and then KillAllProcesses?
Then nothing will be able to reconnect and there will be no race condition...

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName BlockSQL -Service MSSQL -Direction Inbound -Action Block -Enabled True
```

You would of course need to call the SetOffline method locally then since MSSQL is blocked from any comunication over the network.

And when you're done taking the DB:s offline, just delete the firewall rule...

```
Remove-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName BlockSQL
```